# Inner beans receive ApplicationEvents?

Tags: spring

I have a configuration like this

```
<bean id="outer" class="someclass" scope="singleton">
     <property name="p">
         <bean class="otherclass"/>
     </property>
</bean>
```

The `otherclass` implements the `ApplicationListener` interface. But this gives me the following error:

> Inner bean '*name*' implements `ApplicationListener` interface but is not reachable for event multicasting by its containing `ApplicationContext` because it does not have singleton scope. Only top-level listener beans are allowed to be of non-singleton scope.

As far as I can find elsewhere in the Spring documentation the inner beans are considered singletons when the outer bean is a singleton.

I have had it working previously, but am unsure what changed. I also tried specifying scope="singleton" and id on the inner bean, but it didn't change anything.

Why can't my inner bean receve `ApplicationEvents`?

Comment: Did you try to set `scope="singleton"` on the inner bean?

Comment: Why does the error talk about a bean named `telegraph`? Where is this bean declared?

Comment: Yes I tried scope="singleton" - question updated.

Comment: "telegraph" is the actual name of the inner bean, although removed in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can find elsewhere in the Spring documentation the inner beans are considered singletons when the outer bean is a singleton.

Inner beans are always *prototype* scoped ([ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inner-beans)), but they only get instantiated once when used within a singleton bean simply because there's no way to reference them from more than one place in the configuration.

If you want your `otherclass` bean to receive events you'll have to make it a top-level singleton bean in its own right

```
<bean id="otherclass-bean" class="otherclass" scope="singleton"/>

<bean id="outer" class="someclass" scope="singleton">
     <property name="p">
         <ref local="otherclass-bean"/>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: But I would think the last part of the error message "Only top-level listener beans are allowed to be of non-singleton scope" indicates that I could have non-top-level singleton beans?

Comment: @DennisThrysøe It is a bit of a confusing message but no, you can't.  Non-top-level beans are always prototype.  I think the message is saying that you can have non-singleton top-level beans, rather than non-top-level singletons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually turned out to be caused by some unrelated code that overrode the name of the bean. So my orignal scenario should work on its own.